# Adding Column to Sales Order Report - Unknown Column in Field List Error [Solved]

Tags: magento-1.9, reports, column

got an issue when adding a field to the "Total Ordered Report"
I can add the column section without issue but pulling the data is what is giving me an issue.

I keep getting this error. Both when loading the report page and when trying to rebuild the index - if the index rebuilds successfully then the report page will fix as well.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'o.order_cost_total' in 'field list'' in /var/www/html/coopersdev/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

And I can see it is running through the trace where it sees my `/Model/Resource/Sales/Report/Order/Createdat.php` and in this file I overwrite `_aggregateByField`, I also overwrite `Model_Resource_Sales_Report_Order_Collection` and include the column in my `_getSelectedColumns` function so I know it is there but this error keeps appearing and my lack of understanding is killing me here - I don't see what I am missing, I can open the database and see that my column is there, the last column in the sales_flat_order table but it doesn't seem to find it. Here is my code for both below. (No need to read all of it just look for 'order_cost_total)

The Createdat

```
class XXX_XXX_Model_Resource_Sales_Report_Order_Createdat extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Createdat {

    protected function _aggregateByField($aggregationField, $from, $to)
    {
        Mage::log("createdat Rewrite Fired");
        // convert input dates to UTC to be comparable with DATETIME fields in DB
        $from = $this->_dateToUtc($from);
        $to   = $this->_dateToUtc($to);

        $this->_checkDates($from, $to);
        $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();

        $adapter->beginTransaction();
        try {

            if ($from !== null || $to !== null) {
                $subSelect = $this->_getTableDateRangeSelect(
                    $this->getTable('sales/order'),
                    $aggregationField, $aggregationField, $from, $to
                );
            } else {
                $subSelect = null;
            }
            $this->_clearTableByDateRange($this->getMainTable(), $from, $to, $subSelect);

            $periodExpr = $adapter->getDatePartSql($this->getStoreTZOffsetQuery(
                array('o' => $this->getTable('sales/order')),
                'o.' . $aggregationField,
                $from, $to
            ));

            // Columns list
            $columns = array(
                // convert dates from UTC to current admin timezone
                'period'                         => $periodExpr,
                'store_id'                       => 'o.store_id',
                'order_status'                   => 'o.status',
                'order_cost_total'               => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(o.order_cost_total)'),
                'orders_count'                   => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(o.entity_id)'),
                'total_qty_ordered'              => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(oi.total_qty_ordered)'),
                'total_qty_invoiced'             => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(oi.total_qty_invoiced)'),
                'total_income_amount'            => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_grand_total', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_canceled',0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate',0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_revenue_amount'           => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)) * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_invoiced', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_profit_amount'            => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM(((%s - %s) - (%s - %s) - (%s - %s) - %s) * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_paid', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_invoiced_cost', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_invoiced_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM(%s * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_invoiced', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_canceled_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM(%s * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_canceled', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_paid_amount'              => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM(%s * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_paid', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_refunded_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM(%s * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_total_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_tax_amount'               => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_amount', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_canceled', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_tax_amount_actual'        => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((%s -%s) * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_tax_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_shipping_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_amount', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_canceled', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_shipping_amount_actual'   => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_shipping_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_discount_amount'          => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((ABS(%s) - %s) * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_amount', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_canceled', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                ),
                'total_discount_amount_actual'   => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((%s - %s) * %s)',
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_invoiced', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_discount_refunded', 0),
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('o.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                )
            );

            $select          = $adapter->select();
            $selectOrderItem = $adapter->select();

            $qtyCanceledExpr = $adapter->getIfNullSql('qty_canceled', 0);
            $cols            = array(
                'order_id'           => 'order_id',
                'total_qty_ordered'  => new Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(qty_ordered - {$qtyCanceledExpr})"),
                'total_qty_invoiced' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(qty_invoiced)'),
            );
            $selectOrderItem->from($this->getTable('sales/order_item'), $cols)
                ->where('parent_item_id IS NULL')
                ->group('order_id');

            $select->from(array('o' => $this->getTable('sales/order')), $columns)
                ->join(array('oi' => $selectOrderItem), 'oi.order_id = o.entity_id', array())
                ->where('o.state NOT IN (?)', array(
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT,
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW
                ));

            if ($subSelect !== null) {
                $select->having($this->_makeConditionFromDateRangeSelect($subSelect, 'period'));
            }

            $select->group(array(
                $periodExpr,
                'o.store_id',
                'o.status',
            ));

            $adapter->query($select->insertFromSelect($this->getMainTable(), array_keys($columns)));

            // setup all columns to select SUM() except period, store_id and order_status
            foreach ($columns as $k => $v) {
                $columns[$k] = new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(' . $k . ')');
            }
            $columns['period']         = 'period';
            $columns['store_id']       = new Zend_Db_Expr(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
            $columns['order_status']   = 'order_status';

            $select->reset();
            $select->from($this->getMainTable(), $columns)
                ->where('store_id <> 0');

            if ($subSelect !== null) {
                $select->where($this->_makeConditionFromDateRangeSelect($subSelect, 'period'));
            }

            $select->group(array(
                'period',
                'order_status'
            ));
            $adapter->query($select->insertFromSelect($this->getMainTable(), array_keys($columns)));
            $adapter->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $adapter->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The Collection

```
class XXX_XXX_Model_Resource_Sales_Report_Order_Collection extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Collection {

        protected function _getSelectedColumns()
        {

            $adapter = $this->getConnection();
            if ('month' == $this->_period) {
                $this->_periodFormat = $adapter->getDateFormatSql('period', '%Y-%m');
            } elseif ('year' == $this->_period) {
                $this->_periodFormat = $adapter->getDateExtractSql('period', Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INTERVAL_YEAR);
            } else {
                $this->_periodFormat = $adapter->getDateFormatSql('period', '%Y-%m-%d');
            }

            if (!$this->isTotals()) {
                $this->_selectedColumns = array(
                    'period'                         => $this->_periodFormat,
                    'orders_count'                   => 'SUM(orders_count)',
                    'order_cost_total'               => 'SUM(order_cost_total)',
                    'total_qty_ordered'              => 'SUM(total_qty_ordered)',
                    'total_qty_invoiced'             => 'SUM(total_qty_invoiced)',
                    'total_income_amount'            => 'SUM(total_income_amount)',
                    'total_revenue_amount'           => 'SUM(total_revenue_amount)',
                    'total_profit_amount'            => 'SUM(total_profit_amount)',
                    'total_invoiced_amount'          => 'SUM(total_invoiced_amount)',
                    'total_canceled_amount'          => 'SUM(total_canceled_amount)',
                    'total_paid_amount'              => 'SUM(total_paid_amount)',
                    'total_refunded_amount'          => 'SUM(total_refunded_amount)',
                    'total_tax_amount'               => 'SUM(total_tax_amount)',
                    'total_tax_amount_actual'        => 'SUM(total_tax_amount_actual)',
                    'total_shipping_amount'          => 'SUM(total_shipping_amount)',
                    'total_shipping_amount_actual'   => 'SUM(total_shipping_amount_actual)',
                    'total_discount_amount'          => 'SUM(total_discount_amount)',
                    'total_discount_amount_actual'   => 'SUM(total_discount_amount_actual)',
                );
            }

            if ($this->isTotals()) {
                $this->_selectedColumns = $this->getAggregatedColumns();
            }

            return $this->_selectedColumns;
        }
    }
```

Is anyone able to help me at all or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The Answer? Don't be a moron.

I forgot to push my SQL installer update that added the column to the sales_order_aggregated_created and the sales_order_aggregated_updated tables.

I just assumed it must not be reading it from the sales/order table since the installer was in there when I double checked I noticed the column wasn't actually there.

So if you ever wish to add a column to this report.  Update the collection.php the createdat.php, make an observer to do what you wish and ensure your column creations on the sales/order (or order item if you are using that), sales/order_aggregated_created, and sales/order_aggregated_updated are all in place.